# Using OpenGL ES properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I am making a simple game (using the book "iPhone and iPad Game Development for Dummies), but I cannot get it to work. I am making the sample application that is used in the book, so I think I have the correct code. Here is the problem.

I put in the code for OpenGL ES, but I am getting a lot of warnings. Here is the code.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

@interface OpenGL : UIView {
EAGLContext *context;
GLuint *framebuffer;
GLuint *colorRenderBuffer;
GLuint *depthBuffer;
}

- (void) prepareOpenGL;
- (void) render;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "OpenGL.h"


@implementation OpenGL

- (void) awakeFromNib; {
    [self prepareOpenGL];
    [self render];
}

- (void) prepareOpenGL; {
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);

GLint height, width;
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &width);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &height);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create a complete render buffer!");
}
}

- (void) render; {
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
glClearColor(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

+ (Class) layerClass; {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

These are the types of warnings I am getting (I cannot put them all in because there are a lot of them):

`Passing argument 2 of 'glGenFramebuffers' from incompatible pointer type.`
`Passing argument 2 of 'glBindFramebuffers' from incompatible pointer type.`
`Passing argument 2 of 'glGenRenderbuffers' from incompatible pointer type.`
`Passing argument 2 of 'glBindRenderbuffers' from incompatible pointer type.`

So, if all of this came out of the book, why am I getting these warnings? Am I not importing the right files? I really cannot give you much more information than this because I have no idea about what caused this, and I am totally new to OpenGL ES. Thanks for any and all help!

EDIT: One more thing. I get the warnings wherever things like `glGenFramebuffers` are used.

Comment: The warning is quite obvious and I doubt that you really first tried yourself to figure the problem out.

Comment: As I said, I don't know anything about OpenGL. I was using the book so I could learn a bit of it. However, the guy that wrote the book did not say anything about the warnings.

Comment: So see Matias Valdenegro's answer. Just saying I copied everything from the book, doesn't free you from thinking about, what these functions take as arguments and what the type of the variables is that you call them with.

Comment: That is not what I intended to say. I meant to say that because I do not know about this, I cannot debug it properly. I _am_ learning it, so I will soon be able to debug it. Right now, the problem is that, although the errors are obvious, I did not know how to fix them. However, you may notice that I said "Am I not importing the right files?". That is because I did not know if the things I were using were infact correct, but from the wrong file.

Comment: I understand your point, but the fact is that these errors are not OpenGL specific but pure Objective-C (or even C) usage errors. And I assume you're fit in Objective-C when trying to learn OpenGL. I know ,that you couldn't know this, but a small look at the function signature and your variables is enough (and the warnings point you at this), OpenGL or not. If really tried to solve it yourself before asking the question, then pardon me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glGen* functions take a size and a pointer to a GLuint, and you're passing the address of a pointer to a GLuint (a GLuint **), which is what triggers the warning.

Just pass the pointer directly, like this:

glGenFramebuffers(1, framebuffer);
   glGenRenderbuffers(1, colorRenderBuffer);
   glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthBuffer);

Also don't forget to allocate memory before passing it to OpenGL.

Comment: Or even better, stay wioth your syntax and just declare your buffer variables as GLuint. So you do not have to allocate memory and dereference the variables everytime you use them.